# Why does git fix-up care about merge resolution?

Tags: git

So merge resolution is important when we have two branches A and B writing changes to the same file and we don't know what the appropriate end state F_Z should be, possibly F_A, F_B or some combination of the two. However if I'm doing a `git rebase` like

`pick
fixup
fixup
...
fixup`

where the F_Z is already known and the intermediate commits are being deleted, why do I have to merge every conflicting commit? Is there a way to skip having to do this? I really just want to clean up my commit history and without affect F_Z.

Comment: If you have `pick A` followed by `fixup B` and `fixup C`, which of the  three is a merge commit? Is this your pattern, or do you have multiple pickups/fixups in the same interactive rebase?

Comment: I suppose B would have been a merge with merge conflicts that were manually resolved at the time B was committed/merged to this branch. My annoyance was that I've already handled the merge resolution, but rebase asks me to do it again, for every conflict in the rebase history, even though I already have a well defined end state. It sounds like this `git rerere` solves this use case however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is solved by a pretty much unheard of function called git rerere

https://github.com/PackardChan/git-scm.com/blob/blog-revive/app/views/blog/posts/2010-03-08-rerere.markdown

use /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/rerere-train.sh to train rerere from your existing merge commit resolution